# MySQL: INSERT error "Cannot be NULL" -- DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, activerecord

In fact there are so many similar questions, I could not solve this problem.
I am using codeigniter framework. When I call `insert` method of ActiveRecord by passing a php object, it send all properties either by its value or as null. It causes `cannot be null.` error.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `scheduledTasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `createTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `executionTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ownerUserId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjectUserId` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `detail` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `isExecuted` int(1) DEFAULT '0'
);
ALTER TABLE `scheduledTasks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `scheduledTasks`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Query I tried:

```
INSERT INTO `scheduledTasks` (`id`, `type`, `createTime`, `executionTime`, `ownerUserId`, `detail`, `isExecuted`)
VALUES (NULL, 'QuoteRequest', NULL, NULL, '926', NULL, NULL)
```

Mysql Version:

```
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

I have

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | OFF
```

and sql mode is

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode                                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: If `NULL` can trigger the `DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP`, then `NOT NULL` would be your problem. Otherwise, try inserting nothing for `createTime` and `executionTime` and see if that will trigger `DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP`. The manual is tricky. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: The manual says that you can use `NULL` to set a `TIMESTAMP`, but it does not say the same about setting `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Discussion

The [MySQL 5.7 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) states that...

> In addition, you can initialize or update any ***TIMESTAMP*** column to the
>   current date and time by assigning it a ***NULL*** value, unless it has been
>   defined with the NULL attribute to permit NULL values.

The manual does not say you can do this for `DATETIME` fields. The best thing to do would be to supply no values in your `INSERT` query for the `createTime` and `executionTime` fields. That should give you the `DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP`. If that fails, well, I tried.

```
INSERT INTO `scheduledTasks` (`id`, `type`, `createTime`, `executionTime`, `ownerUserId`, `detail`, `isExecuted`)
VALUES (NULL, 'QuoteRequest', , , '926', NULL, NULL)
```

Also, keep this in mind about [MySQL default values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html), even though your `DATETIME` columns *do have* an explicit `DEFAULT` clause.

> For data entry into a `NOT NULL` column that has *no explicit* `DEFAULT`
>   clause, if an `INSERT` or REPLACE statement includes *no value for the*
>   *column*, or an UPDATE statement sets the column to NULL, MySQL handles
>   the column according to the ***SQL mode*** in effect at the time:
>
> If ***strict SQL mode is enabled***, an error occurs for transactional tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables,
>   an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row
>   of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows will have been
>   inserted.
>
> If ***strict mode is not enabled***, MySQL sets the column to the ***implicit default value*** for the column data type.

Finally, about [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) in the MySQL Manual:

> For `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, MySQL converts an invalid value to the
>   closest valid value for the column and inserts the adjusted value. If
>   a value is missing, MySQL inserts the *implicit default value* for the
>   column data type. In either case, MySQL generates a warning rather
>   than an error and continues processing the statement. Implicit
>   defaults are described in Section 12.7, “Data Type Default Values”.

### Conclusion

In summary, if you are in *strict mode* (which you are, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`) and have `DATETIME` columns set to `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and then you supply `NULL` values during an `INSERT`, and then subsequently you get a "*cannot be NULL*" error, ... next time around do not supply values to the `DATETIME` fields.

If your framework cannot be setup to omit values during `INSERT`, and changing the SQL mode does not work, then altering the table to use (gasp) `TIMESTAMP` may be your only option to use `NULL` in strict mode and have a `DEFAULT TIMESTAMP` appear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed the type to TIMESTAMP and it works as I wanted to be.

Comment: Just be careful about the *range of dates* you need to use. I believe `TIMESTAMP` starts in 1970 and is only good until 2038.

Comment: Thanks. This table is for scheduled tasks, so, I think 2038 will be enough for now. :D